# Mutex for SPI communication

Tags: c++, mutex, spi

Let's say I have multiple nodes that perform SPI communication over a common MISO MOSI channel along with different GPIO pins to perform the chip select option as shown in the class below

```cpp
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include<mutex>
#include<stdint.h>

class spi
{
private:
    static std::mutex mtx;

public:
    writeSPI(int gpio, uint8_t reg, char* buf)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        //opening chip select sequence for the received gpio
        //spi sequence to write data to target
        //closing chip select sequence for the received gpio
        mtx.unlock();
    }
};
#endif
```

The individual nodes create their own instances of the class through an include directive and call the `writeSPI(int, uint8_t, char)` function as shown below

```cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    spi instance;
    while(true)
    {
        instance.writeSPI(/* required args*/);
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility that the assigned `buf` gets written to the wrong `gpio` clip select? If this is the wrong method for handling the task, what is the correct alternative ?

Comment: I don't see any threads in your code, so if there is no threads, then you don't even need `mutex` as all operations will be executed sequentially.

Comment: Multiple nodes will be making their own instances so technically there will be multiple instances required to be handled by a mutex.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand what you mean. Multiple instances of `spi` object in one process? Or multiple processes each of which have single `spi` instance? You code suggest later, and in this case single anonymous `mutex` won't work. If I'm remember correctly there should be named mutex in Linux and that should work.

Comment: Multiple processes have their own `spi` instance. The objective is to block the next process instance object from calling `writeSPI(...)` function until the previous instance object present in another process has completed the whole execution of the function.

Comment: In this case you need to use interprocess mutex, we don't have it in standard library, but it seems to be in boost or you can directly use OS functions.

Answer (score 2):

The static std::mutex will guard correctly against a multi threaded access to writeSPI(...).

You should not call lock/unlock manually though, use std::unique_lock instead to guard against bugs.

Comment: This application sounds like it's for a micro. I'm wondering if their'd be any performance improvement by using `std::lock_guard` as it has less features than `std::unique_lock`?